# how to disable content becoming smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have a page and when I make the browser window horizontally smaller, the content also becomes narrower and smaller, how do I fix this? I just want the content to maintain 100% width and if browser window is small display horizontal scrollbar instead.

You can see it [**HERE**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kch0ib8t50y46pg/1.html), try making the browser window smaller.

I have tried also making the content width like 1000px, but it doesn't work as expected.

Here is CSS code:

```
body {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/UAq9egG.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.content {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    margin: 30px;
}

p {
    color: white;
}
```

Here is also **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9pcrqv9/)**

Comment: read again, that doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: yes I will see horizontal bar, but if the browser window is normal it will look like this http://i.imgur.com/XQJWFos.png

Comment: @user2570380 I think he actually means inside the `div` itself

Comment: @user2570380 yes, you are right

Comment: hmm yes, fixed width actually..

Answer (score 0):

set the width of content to 1000 px, worked fine for me.

If you open up developer tools and assign the content class 1000px it shows a horizontal scrollbar instead of stretching the content.

Comment: my screen is 1366x768 pixels and when i try that the site will look like this http://i.imgur.com/XQJWFos.png

Comment: if you want a scrollbar to appear instead of having your content stretch to fit the window you define the width. if you want the scroll bar the width needs to be wider than the window. the browser by default will provide scroll bars for content that exceeds its width or height. in your case you would need to set the width of content greater than 1366 in width for example

Answer (score 0):

For me is working fine just by adding 1000px in the .content class:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  margin: 30px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

If you want different a different behavior for different browser sizes. You may takea look at CSS @media query

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply

```
white-space:nowrap; 
flot: left;
```

at your content.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9pcrqv9/1/

Comment: `I have tried also making the content width like 1000px, but it doesn't work as expected.` He means he wants a fixed with and make the overflow to be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a better answer.
Using
`overflow-x:scroll`
you can easily make the content to scroll horizontally.

So better create a container for .content, assign it the properties .content has got, and then, put inside the inner div the actual content with a fixed with of 1000px and a overflow-x: scroll